<sqlite> - Order by a specific pattern?
I would like to get my entries ordered by a specific pattern.
for example i have an array like this
arr = [2,5,3,9,4]

Now I want to get the entries from my db by ID in the order of the array. I would like to use sql only for this, is it possible?
SELECT * FROM costumers WHERE id = ???  [ORDER BY arr]

thanx

Which dbms are you using? Arrays and SQL isn't a common combination.

Please provide sample input data and the expected result. Your question is very unclear. Where should for example id 6, id 7 or id 10 or id 200 appear?

this is just an example. there are no other id's than in the array. all i wanted is sorting the entries according the order in the array. i solved it by the answer in the last post. thank you

ok i found the solution
WITH oder_d (id, sort_order) AS (
    VALUES
    (2, 1),
    (5, 2),
    (3, 3),
    (9, 4),
    (4, 5)
)
SELECT c.* FROM costumers c
JOIN oder_d o ON c.id = o.id
ORDER BY o.sort_order;

thanks anyway

Your question is still much too vague, so both questions and answer are not really helpful. Could you please improve the question, so other people who might have similar questions can see whether your answer help them or not? See my comment below your question.

Either a CASE WHEN expression - or a join with a mapping table, as you did - that will give you a reliable sorting order - well done!

If you use MySQL, you can use ORDER BY FIELD:
SELECT * FROM costumers ORDER BY FIELD(id,2,5,3,9,4);


When giving a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified, at least tell OP and the rest of us which dbms it's for.

thanks for your comments, just added the db name

thank you for your response. i would like to use it in sqlite. sqlite does not have a FIELD() function. is there something i could use in sqlite instead of FIELD?

@IlanSagital, add a  tag to your question, to get suitable answers.

ok thanks jarlh done, i am new to stackoverflow :)

For a fully portable version, if the values you want to arrow-wise order by, are in a column id, I would go:
ORDER BY 
  CASE id
    WHEN 2 THEN 1
    WHEN 5 THEN 2
    WHEN 3 THEN 3
    WHEN 9 THEN 4
    WHEN 4 THEN 5
  END;

But - in a DBMS supporting arrays, you might have other possibilities - like extracting the i-th element of the array - by having the i value from somewhere else in the query, and just sorting by i , for example.
If you supply the DBMS you're working with - and the full query, perhaps, or a simplified version of it - we can help better.
